# Hide empty <li>

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, hide, trim

I want to hide all the `<li>` if they are empty or if there any blank space in `<li>`.

I am doing it like this:

```
$("li:empty").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
```

Is this the wrong syntax?

If I create a class to make empty `<li>` invisible, it works fine. Like this:

```
$("li[class='hideLi']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
```

But I don't know which `<li>` will be empty .

Can anybody help me plz.
I want to do `display=none` if the `<li>` is empty.

Here is my code:-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>




<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:empty").css('display', 'none');
     $("div:empty").css('display', 'none');
     $(!$.trim('li:empty')).hide();
     $("li[class='hideLi']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
  });
  </script>

<ul>
  <li style="border:red solid 1px ">HI</li>
  <li style="border:green solid 1px ">  </li>
    <li style="border:blue solid 1px " class="hideLi">  </li>
  </ul>
```

Thanks,

Comment: The `:empty` selector will pick up only those nodes that have nothing -- not even a space -- in them. That's the problem. `$('li:empty')` has **filtered out** those `li` nodes with space in it. So the later filter is useless. Try @Vassilis 's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
}).hide()
```

Comment: What if I have this: `<li><a></a></li>`. If the anchor text is empty, hide the `LI`. Update: Resolved it. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 9):

You can use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

To make this work if you have spaces, you can use [jQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
$("li").each(function() {

    if(!$.trim($(this).html())) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

working example: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8B22K/1/)

Comment: `$(!$.trim("li:empty")).hide()` is equivalent to `$(!"li:empty").hide()` ==> `$(false).hide()`, so what's the point?

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a working fiddle using `<li>`