# Hide multiple list items if one has no content or empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a whole bunch of list items, and within them are more list items.

For all `<li id="company-name" class="hide">`, I want to detect whether this element is empty.

If it is empty, I want to hide ALL `<li class="hide">` within the direct parent `<ul></ul>` element.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class="greyul">
            <li>Location:</li>
            <li class="hide">Company:</li> <!-- DONT HIDE -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="whiteul">
            <li>Melbourne</li>
            <li id="company-name" class="hide"></li> <!-- HIDE -->
            <li class="hide">Sydney</li> <!-- HIDE ALSO-->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are the divs in your html?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide empty <li>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642690/hide-empty-li)

Comment: you have used multiple `id="company-name"` in your HTML, which is not a correct prodedure.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kxzLfc5L/2/ is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8):

You can use simple css selector [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty)

```
.hide:empty{
    display: none;
}
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('.hide:empty').hide();
```

If you want to hide parent div, then you may use:

```
$('.hide:empty').parent().hide();
```

---

As per your updated question, you can use [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) and [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) like this:

```
$('.hide:not(:contains("Company:"))').hide();
```

Comment: +1 for the css solution, but I think you want `$('.hide:empty').hide();` for the jQuery, `is` tests the jquery object and returns a boolean

Comment: Notice that having text, even if it is a single space, won't apply the selector. Text counts as a `Node`. I think that comments will cause the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have used multiple `id="company-name"` in your HTML, which is not a correct procedure. Change them to class.

You can use <kbd>[**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/)</kbd> function to iterate.

```js
$('li.company-name').each(function(){
    if( $.trim($(this).text()) == '')
        $(this).parents('li:first').find('.hide').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="greyul">
      <li>Location:</li>
      <li class="hide">Company:</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="whiteul">
      <li>Melbourne</li>
      <li class="company-name hide">display;none; on all items with the class 'hide' within THIS PARENT LIST item only, if this li has no content</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <ul class="greyul">
      <li>Location:</li>
      <li class="hide">Company:</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="whiteul">
      <li>Melbourne</li>
      <li class="company-name hide"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <ul class="greyul">
      <li>Location:</li>
      <li class="hide">Company:</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="whiteul">
      <li>Melbourne</li>
      <li class="company-name hide">ABC</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're going for?

*EDIT: fixed answer thanks to @patlkli and @Sphinxxx*

```
$('li#company-name.hide:empty').hide().siblings('li.hide').hide();
```

This hides all empty `<li id="company-name" class="hide">` elements, then hides any neighboring/sibling `<li class="hide">` element, regardless of whether or not they are empty as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/kxzLfc5L/4/

Comment: I think, this is exactly what he described.

You can make it a bit shorter though:
`$("li#company-name.hide:empty").hide().siblings("li.hide").hide();`

Comment: `.is()` returns a boolean and can't be used with `.hide()`. Add the filter to the `.siblings()` query instead: `$('li#company-name.hide:empty').hide().siblings('li.hide').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').each(function() { 
    if($(this).html()=="") {
        $(this).addClass('hide'); 
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('hide'); 
    }
});

.hide {
    dispaly:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure javascript solution:

First check for lists which contain empty items and add class 'hasEmptyItems' to them:

```
var emptyItems = document.querySelectorAll('.hide');
for (var i = 0; i < emptyItems.length; i++) {
    if(emptyItems[i].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
        emptyItems[i].parentNode.classList.add('hasEmptyItems');
        break; //stop looping as soon as one empty item is found
    }     
}
```

Next use CSS to hide elements with the 'hide' class within lists with the class 'hasEmptyItems'

```
.hasEmptyItems .hide {
    display: none;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/w0mo2Ljt/7/)

```js
var emptyItems = document.querySelectorAll('.hide');
for (var i = 0; i < emptyItems.length; i++) {
    if(emptyItems[i].innerHTML.trim() === '') {
        emptyItems[i].parentNode.classList.add('hasEmptyItems');
        break; //stop looping as soon as one empty item is found
    }     
}
```

```css
.hasEmptyItems .hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul class="greyul">
      <li>Location:</li>
      <li class="hide">Company:</li>
      <!-- DONT HIDE -->
    </ul>
    <ul class="whiteul">
      <li>Melbourne</li>
      <li id="company-name" class="hide">  </li>
      <!-- HIDE -->
      <li class="hide">Sydney</li>
      <!-- HIDE ALSO-->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and to the point. :)

```
<!-- Script to hide the blank/empty li--> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $('li').filter(function(){ 
    return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';}).hide() });
</script>
```